# Oracle rownum on "parent" table

Tags: java, sql, oracle, rownum

We use Oracle `rownum` to query two tables `t1->t2` which have a one to many relationship:

```
select * from
(
 select t1.key, t1.a, t2.b
  from t1, t2
 where t1.key=t2.key and <filter conditions> 
 order by t1.a, t2.b
)
where rownum <= 500
```

This works fine in that it returns the first 500 rows.   But what we want is to return the first 500 rows from `t1` - and then all the `t2` rows that go along with that.  What is the best way to do that?

We could remove the `rownum` sql usage and in Java just read the first 500 unique `t1.key` values from the resultset (which will be more than 500 total rows in the resultset).  But it's not clear if that would be significantly slower.

Comment: Please provide relevant table structures, sample of data in both tables, and desired result.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can accomplish this by using the `dense_rank()` analytic function:

```
select * from
(
 select t1.key, t1.a, t2.b,
        dense_rank() over (order by t1.a, t1.key) as rnk 
  from t1, t2
 where t1.key=t2.key 
   and <filter conditions> 
)
where rnk <= 500
order by a, b
```

For what it's worth, it would be preferable if you get in the habit of using the ANSI join syntax.

**EDIT**

The above should work fine if `t1.a` is guaranteed to have unique values in `t1`.  If not, then you may find that my query doesn't quite match the `order by` logic of your original query. But I don't know if there is anything I can do.

The problem is that because you order by `t1.a, t2.b`, then, in your original query, there is no guarantee that all the results with the same `t1.key` value will be grouped together, which makes it unclear how your "first 500 rows" logic is supposed to work based on `t1.key`.

Comment: It may seem that it would be more efficient to filter by `rnk <= 500` first,  and only then do the join (what if table `t1` has 30 million rows?) In some cases the optimizer will push the conditions down to subqueries or individual tables in a join, etc., but I am not sure if that is true for analytical functions... ??

Comment: @mathguy: Actually, more so than the performance of it, the more I think about it, the less I'm confident that my query is accurate.  I'm struggling with the fact that the `order by` is on `a, b`, while the only known unique key in `t1` is `key`.  There is something I'm not doing right.

Comment: Also you probably meant `rank` - `dense_rank` up to 500 may return 700 rows. Or, if they don't care about ties and they want 500 rows, `row_number` would be the standard choice.

Comment: @mathguy: Well, I think that's what OP wanted.  If there are 500 distinct keys that return 700 rows joined with `t2`, then he wants the 700 rows.

Comment: Interesting... I tested quickly on the HR schema, with the `dense_rank` before or after the join. The plans are different, but the cost happens to be the same. This is probably because EMPLOYEES has only 140 rows or so; wonder if it had 1 million rows if the conclusion would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "first 500 rows of a table", because tables represent *unordered* sets.  But, if you mean by `t1.a`, then this might be faster:

```
select . . .
from (select t.*
      from (select t1.*, 
            from t1
            where exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.key = t1.key and <conditions>)
            order by t1.a
           ) t1
      where rownum <= 500
     ) join
     t2
     on t1.key = t2.key and <filter conditions> 
order by t1.a, t2.b;
```

Whether this is faster depends on whether the subquery can make use of indexes.  Without the filter condition, then an index on `t1(a, key)` would work.  It is unclear if that would work with the unknown conditions.